# Pyramid: ACE order in ACL

Tags: python, pyramid

I want to allow a permission on non-authenticated users, but deny it for authenticated ones.

```
# works
__acl__ = [
    (Deny, Authenticated, 'something'),
    (Allow, Everyone, 'something'),
]

# order changed -- DOES NOT WORK
__acl__ = [
    (Allow, Everyone, 'something'),
    (Deny, Authenticated, 'something'),
]
```

My question is: is this the right way to filter out non-authenticated users from the authenticated ones. Is there a *more explicit* way to do this in Pyramid? How can I delineate non-authenticated users by saying `NonAuthenticated` (which is `Everyone - Authenticated`).

A more generic question is: How should we filter users that are in one group but not in the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Authenticated` and `Everyone` are principals (in fact, they are just strings). Each user have a list of principals (by default `[username, Authenticated, Everyone]` for authenticated users, `[Everyone]` for the others). You can't do ensemble operations on the principals, so it's not possible to define a `NonAuthenticated` computed from `Everyone` and `Authenticated`.

What you can do is use the order of the ACL to state what you want. The [documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/narr/security.html#elements-of-an-acl) mentions that ACLs are processed in order, and the first one that match a principal of the user is user. So if you want to give access to users in group A except if they are in group B (how have principal 'group:A', but not 'group:B'), you can write.

```
__acl__ = [
    (Deny, 'group:B', 'something'),   # If user in B, deny
    (Allow, 'group:A', 'something'),  # Else (=if user not in B), if user in A, allow
    (Deny, Everyone, 'something'),    # Else, Deny
]
```